# BackgroundWorker RunWorkerCompleted in a Component

Tags: .net, backgroundworker

I'm familiar with the following:

"If the operation raises an exception that your code does not handle, the BackgroundWorker  catches the exception and passes it into the RunWorkerCompleted  event handler, where it is exposed as the Error  property of System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs. If you are running under the Visual Studio debugger, the debugger will break at the point in the DoWork event handler where the unhandled exception was raised."

However, I've encountered a weird glitch.

In my component, there's an instance of BackgroundWorker.

Even though it's not running in the debugger, the exception remains unhandled by the worker.

Even simplified code produces an unhandled exception (and RunWorkerCompleted doesn't fire):

```
Throw New ArgumentException("Test")
```

The main thing is the code of RunWorkerComplete:

```
RaiseEvent UpdateComplete(Me, New AsyncCompletedEventArgs(e.Error, e.Cancelled, e.Result))
```

I need the component to expose the worker exception through a public event.

If I remove the RaiseEvent call, the exception becomes handled by the worker, and accessible through e.Error.

Apparently, raising an event causes the worker to miss the exception. How can that be?

**Full Code:**

Component:

```
Private Sub workerDownloader_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)

        RaiseEvent UpdateComplete(Me, New AsyncCompletedEventArgs(e.Error, e.Cancelled, e.Result))

End Sub

Private Sub workerDownloader_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
        Throw New ArgumentException("Test")
End Sub
```

Host app (WinForms):

```
Private Sub Connector1_UpdateComplete(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs) Handles Connector1.UpdateComplete
        If e.Error IsNot Nothing Then MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString)
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you provide a complete code example? I'm not clear on what `RunWorkerComplete` is.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a more detailed explanation of why I believe you are running into this problem. Take a look and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update based on your updates to the question...
I've mocked this up in C# code and it looks like it's a (cross thread?) issue trying to pass the Result from the event args to the AsyncCompletedEventArgs.

Passing the error and the cancel works, but when I try to pass the result object, it dies. Do you need the result object in the event?

```
UpdateComplete(this, new AsyncCompletedEventArgs(e.Error, e.Cancelled, null));
```

Comment: I don't need a result this time, and that works, thanks. But it's a bit weird anyways, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

It could be that your `e.Result` is throwing its own exception.

From [the MSDN documentation on `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.runworkercompletedeventargs.result.aspx):

> Your `RunWorkerCompleted` event
>   handler should always check the
>   `Error` and `Cancelled` properties
>   before accessing the `Result`
>   property. If an exception was raised
>   or if the operation was canceled,
>   accessing the `Result` property raises
>   an exception.

Specifically, it will raise a `TargetInvocationException`.

In the code you've posted, you are constructing a new `AsyncCompletedEventArgs` object from the argument passed through your `RunWorkerCompleted` event. I am not sure what your rationale for this is, but it looks to *me* like an unnecessary step since `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs` *inherits* from `AsyncCompletedEventArgs` -- and so you can just pass your `e` (a `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs` object) to your `UpdateComplete` event:

```
Private Sub workerDownloader_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent UpdateComplete(Me, e)
End Sub
```

Now, here's why this might fix your problem (and why the MSDN link I posted is relevant): the way you're *currently* doing it, you are accessing `e.Result` in your call to the constructor for `AsyncCompletedEventArgs`. By accessing the property there, before first checking `e.Error`, you are creating a scenario where an exception is thrown in the process of evaluating the parameters to pass to `UpdateComplete`. Because of this exception, your `RaiseEvent` line cannot finish what it's doing; hence, your `UpdateComplete` event is not being raised.

Comment: That's not the case, as the unhandled exception is the one I thrown (ArgumentException - "Test"). 
I use "If e.Error IsNot Nothing Then MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString)"
Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Sphynx, when you create a `AsyncCompletedEventArgs` you are accessing the `e.Result` without checking if there was an error or if the worker was canceled.